# Why is PHP mysql_insert_id() returning zero?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have the following code. The $last_id is always showing zero. I do have a column in the "source" table that has auto-increment id. What is the problem with this code?

index.php:

```
<?php
// connect to the database
include('connect-db.php');
$last_id = mysql_insert_id($connection);
$content = "Please type your content here!";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

 <script type="text/javascript"> 

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myform").submit( function () {    
              $.post(
               'submit.php',
                $(this).serialize(),
                    function(data){
                        alert("Your ID: <?php echo $last_id;?>");

                    }
              );
              return false;   
            });   
        });
</script> 


  </head>
  <body>

<div id="header" >

<form action="submit.php" method="post" id="myform">
<textarea id="editor" name="editor" id="editor"><?php echo $content; ?></textarea>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit"/>

</form>

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

connect-db:

```
<?php
 $server = 'localhost';
 $user = 'mumbo';
 $pass = 'mumbo123';
 $db = 'jumbo';

 $connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) 
 or die ("Could not connect to server ... \n" . mysql_error ());
 mysql_select_db($db) 
 or die ("Could not connect to database ... \n" . mysql_error ());
?>
```

submit.php:

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
$submit_date = date("Ymd");
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']));
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($content != '') {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO source (submit_date, ip, content) values('$submit_date','$ip_address','$content')") or die(mysql_error());    
mysql_close($connection);
}
```

?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this as submit.php:

```
<?php
include('connect-db.php');
$submit_date = date("Ymd");
$content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']));
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($content != '') {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO source (submit_date, ip, content) values('$submit_date','$ip_address','$content')") or die(mysql_error());    
echo mysql_insert_id();
}
?>
```

and in the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myform").submit( function () {    
              $.post(
               'submit.php',
                $(this).serialize(),
                    function(data){
                        alert("Your ID: " + data);

                    }
              );
              return false;   
            });   
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This line is computed when the original page loads:

```
             alert("Your ID: <?php echo $last_id;?>");
```

So it's effectively:

```
             alert("Your ID: 0");
```

Since all you've done at that point is connect, there is no insert id.  I'm not familiar with jquery, but presumably the data parameter to your callback should contain data about the response from submit.php.  You need to make submit.php return the ID, then get that data through whatever means in jquery, and display it.

Edit:  actually, it looks like what you're doing can't really do what I said, anyhow.

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

You're setting up a handler which is run whenever the form is submitted - however, this is before the submit actually happens, so you can't actually get the ID there.  Your options are to use something like XmlHttpRequest to make an asynchronous call, or have this popup on the submit.php page.

Answer (score 2):

First of all do not use mysql, use mysqli or pdo, mysql is a deprecated system and should not be used. It is not secure and can be hacked easily.

Second, mysql_insert_id only works if you call it directly after the insert...

AKA

```
if ($content != '') {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO source (submit_date, ip, content) values('$submit_date','$ip_address','$content')") or die(mysql_error());    
  $last_id = mysql_insert_id();
  echo $last_id
mysql_close($connection);
```

then your jquery must say

```
 alert("Your ID: "+data);
```

The function data that is returned is whatever you echo from your script. Jquery retrieves it in whatever callback variable you set (data) and then you can use it.

Comment: no problem. consider using pdo if you are able. Using prepared statements completely secures you from sql injection.